# Handle notifications data Android when re-logging

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

So, I have an app which can receive some notifications. 
Here is the worklow:

1. User log in
2. When logged in, program send request to server which retrieve some data from DB and load the data into Android's terminal memory.

I can send notifications to other users and these users can see them even if the app is closed. 
So far, when the user click on the notification, He/She went through an activity which re-logged him (so, I can send the request to DB and retrieve all the data I need), and I write some notifications related data into `SharedPreferences`.

My problem is the following: the number of notifications received is dynamic. How can I dynamically store some data in Android (without using a remote DB) and retrieve them even if the app is closed? Because, I will need this notification's data in the app. 
I don't think `SharedPreferences` is the convenient way, but can't see what else I can do.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really matter where you store it. As long as it persist it most likely meets your requirements. So either DB or `SharedPreferences` should do the job.

Comment: Yes, it have to be persistent. But I was wondering if it is really a good practice to use `SharedPreferences` this way (since it can contain quite a lot of data)

Comment: Shared preferences is stored in flat XML file. So if you got really a lot (10 is not a lot :) of data, or need to access these data randomly, sqlite may be better choice.

Comment: Do you think 100 (at the very most) is a lot?

Comment: Hard to say as numbers does not matter here. What you should care is performance so if SharedPreferences will work fine for you with your 100 records then it's all fine. Just check.